# Unit Vectors in 3D

Tags: multivariable-calculus, vector-analysis

Hello everyone I am having trouble understanding the question, specifically the $\vec{e}_r$ part, I don't know what it wants me to do\

[The the gradient operator in spherical coordinates is this.](https://wikimedia.org/api/rest_v1/media/math/render/svg/9b2de685e793c37746b93b9eeba4bdf8f539f320)

So I got:

$$<e^{\sin \left(x\right)}\cos \left(x\right), \sqrt{x^2+y^2+z^2}, xyz>$$

Is this the answer they want? Or are they asking for something completely different, because I'm really confused reading the problem and don't understand

Edit:

So here is the final correct answer: $$<e^{\sin \left(x\right)}\cos \left(x\right), 0, 0>$$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is something wrong with you computation. The radius $r = r(x,y,z) = \sqrt{x^2+y^2+z^2}$. Do you see now what your error was?

$\textbf{Edit}$: Also, remember that $e_r$ is just fancy notation for:

$$\frac{\langle x,y,z\rangle}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2+z^2}}$$

Comment: Never mind. You have: $$\phi = \phi(x,y,z) = e^{\sin\left(\sqrt{x^2+y^2+z^2}\right)}$$ so yes, do exactly what you suggested in the comment you gave. Remember that $\phi$ measures the angle from the positive $z$-axis to the point $(x,y,z)$ i.e $\phi$ is determined by $(x,y,z)$. Do this and let me know what you get, it should be the right answer.

Comment: You've done everything right! What can you factor out now to recover $e_r$?

Comment: You are literally right at the answer! Do you see $e_r$ in your calculation? If so, isolate it! They are asking you to say something like $\nabla \phi = (\textbf{something}) \cdot e_r$. What is $\textbf{something}$ here?

Comment: That's it! You can simplify that and say; $$\nabla \phi = e^{\sin(r)} \cos (r) \cdot \vec{e}_r$$

Comment: Oh I understand the question now, thank you so much. When they say to express it in terms of $e_r$ it means they wanted me to write the same answer as what $∇ϕ$ is, but using $e_r$ in there. Thank you so much!

Comment: No problem. I'm glad you were able to figure it out.

Answer (score 0):

Use $\frac{\delta r}{\delta x}=\frac{x}{r}$,$\frac{\delta r}{\delta y}=\frac{y}{r}$ and $\frac{\delta r}{\delta z}=\frac{z}{r}$.

Then grad$\phi=e^{sin r}cos r(\hat i\frac{\delta r}{\delta x}+\hat j\frac{\delta r}{\delta y}+\hat k\frac{\delta r}{\delta y})$

$=e^{sinr}$$cos r$$\overrightarrow e_r$